# find no of files at download path in objective c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, download, nsfilemanager

i am new to `iPad` developer,

i am making `epub reader` application,

**i want to check how many `.epub` file is there, in it's downloads folder when user downloads any `epub` from internet.**

and finally i want to store name of each epub in my `array`...

How should i implement this ?

**Any help will be appreciated.**

***Thanks In Advance !!***

Comment: What do you mean by download folder?

Comment: path of folder where downloaded file gets stored in device..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorry, for the load in DB here, i found solution,

```
 NSString *files;
    NSDirectoryEnumerator *direnum = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] enumeratorAtPath:basePath];
    NSMutableArray *movfiles = [NSMutableArray array];
    while(files = [direnum nextObject])
    {
        if([[files pathExtension] isEqualToString:@"epub"])
            [movfiles addObject:files];
    }

    for (int i=0; i<[movfiles count]; i++) {
        NSLog(@"array=%@",[movfiles objectAtIndex:i]);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know it's helping you but try it I have used in my app but books are already added in my resource folder

```
NSString *bundleRoot = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
NSFileManager *fm = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSArray *dirContents = [fm contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:bundleRoot error:nil];

NSPredicate *fltr = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self ENDSWITH '.epub'"];
self.onlyJPGs = [dirContents filteredArrayUsingPredicate:fltr];
```

Comment: how  can i open local storage from my app for pasting data at wherever i want? please reply me

Answer (score 0):

you will not have access to that folder, if you do by any mean, then your app will be rejected

Comment: download path might be iPhone simulator path in my mac machine... but i am not sure about this.

Comment: you mean files downloaded by safari?

Comment: then definitely you will cant access them, you can access files downloaded by your application only, and not files outside your sandbox